# jericho-html - text extracting and incorrect text lenght

Tags: java, gwt, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

Today I tried to use the lib as [jericho-html-3.2](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) to [extract text from simple html](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/TextExtractor.html)... And I faced a strange text fake length problem as follows:

if I have html as this one

```
Hello World :)<br><br>Hello World :(<br><br>Hello World ;)<br>
```

...my [RichTextArea](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.html) `getText().length()` returns **42** that is correct length actually but when I try to extract text from this html with code like a

```
        Source source = new Source(html);
    String text = source.getTextExtractor().toString();
```

... the `text.length()` returns **44**

So I don't get it why text which length is **42** turns into text which length is **44** and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to dig it deeper and I think the wrong text length becomes from html line breakers because the jericho html-parser ***for some reason replaces new line breakers with spaces*** or something...

As for now, I cannot say for sure which more tags does it replace to which characters but as for my case I just tried to do some walk-around [using regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) like this (see snippet)

```
html=html.replaceAll("<br>","");

Source source = new Source(html);
String text = source.getTextExtractor().toString();
```

... so now it really returns original text length as **42** :)

I hope the tip saves one day

---

Thank you all for help

Answer (score 0):

It is 44 only, you need to consider all the 
 tags as one character each, spaces as one character each and all the smileys as one character each.

```
H(1)e(2)l(3)l(4)o(5) (6)W(7)o(8)r(9)l(10)d(11) (12):)(13)<br>(14)<br>(15)H(16)e(17)l(18)l(19)o(20) (21)W(22)o(23)r(24)l(25)d(26) (27:((28)<br>(29)<br>(30)H(31)e(32)l(33)l(34)o(35) (36)W(37)o(38)r(39)l(40)d(41) (42);)(43)<br>(44)
```

Comment: No, actually I want to have spaces in my extracted text that's OK; I just want to have its length as the original String had... That is the question about